# How to integrate truecaller SDK in flutter apps?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to use **Truecaller** authentication service. Through Truecaller documentation I did not understand how to integrate **Truecaller SDK** into my **flutter apps**.

Comment: You can use Truecaller SDK in your pod file(native code) because Truecaller sdk not available in flutter. Please see this [link](https://developer.truecaller.com/for-mobile-apps). You can create method channel in native code and pass value in flutter code.

Comment: Actually I am new so can you plz explain through coding sample.

Comment: you need method channel code to pass data from native to flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter_truecaller plugin.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_truecaller

Verification via this plugin enables you to quickly verify / signup / login your users on the basis of their mobile number

Comment: Though this answer is in the right direction, additional text specifying explaining relevant part from the link-resource would be more helpful.